# magento2 verifies the order before it is generated

Tags: magento2

magento2.4.5 CE Before generating the order, I need to call the erp third-party system to verify whether the inventory is satisfied and whether the product is removed from the shelves. How should I operate

Answer (score 0):

You should observe on order place before event, and add your code in that observer to consult with 3rd party system related to inventory. If all good is received from the 3rd party, you can simply return from the observer, and in case there's an issue with inventory, you can return an exception from the observer with relevant message, which will stop the placing of order on your website.